# Laravel 5 query with variable number of where clauses

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm try to make a tag-based search system similar to the one here on stackoverflow using Laravel and jQuery Token-Input plugin. The contents of the "tags" are then to be used as the query itself, drawn from a list from a different table.

Using Eloquent, I want to build a query based on a variable number of tags in the search bar (limited only by the number of possible tags there can be). It would look something like this if not done as a loop:

```
$query = Model::whereHas('attribute', 'name', '=', 'tag1')
               ->whereHas('attribute', 'name', '=', 'tag2') 
               ->whereHas('attribute', 'name', '=', 'tag3')
               // Repeat until...
               ->get();
```

The `'attribute'` in question is actually something drawn from a pivot table.
Obviously, I *want* it to be in the form of a loop since we're dealing with a variable number of tags. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Fixed it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can so something like this:

```
$query = Model::whereHas('attribute', 'name', '=', 'tag1');
foreach ($other_tags as $tag) {
    $query = $query->whereHas('attribute', 'name', '=', $tag);
}
print_r($query->get());
```

The only hint here is that you need to use **first** tag to init `Model::whereHas`. Other tags can be iterated over and each one will be added to `$query`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tags in array like this

```
$tags = [ 'tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4', ...];
```

then you can simply use whereIn

```
$results = Model::whereHas('attribute', function($query) use ($tags) {
    $query->whereIn('name', $tags);
})->get();
```